# Uninstaling Geonode

Tags: python, ubuntu, apt-get

I have an installation of Geonode R 2.01 running under Ubuntu 12.04.  I tried to uninstall it using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge geonode
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
sudo rm –r /etc/geonode
```

Then I tried to reinstall it using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geonode/release
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install geonode
geonode createsuperuser
sudo geonode-updateip 127.0.0.1
```

In the latest command I had the error that I uploaded in the file so I assume that there is a file or subdirectory that I didn't delete it.  I tried to look at it  but without success.   Does any one have an idea of the file or sub directory that  I missed it.

[image: LoadDescription]

Comment: I think I found the answer,  I have to remove Apache7 too. The instruction will do  like this: sudo apt-get purge tomcat7 geoserver-geonode geonode.   I will go to the client on Monday and I will let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional to remove Apache, I had to uninstall the  layers installed in Geoserver. In my version are located  in /var/lib/geoserver/geonode-data/, then reinstall the whole thing and should work.